# Extracting text out of XML

Tags: xml, notepad++, cdata

I'm looking for a way to extract all text sections in an XML file found in `<!CDATA[]>`. Is there a program or a quick way to do it yourself? I am using notepad++ to edit the XML file. Perhaps there is a plugin I'm not yet aware of I could use?

Answer (score 0):

you can use minidom from xml.dom library in python;
here's the link where you can find some examples:

[https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html](http://minidom)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Notepad++'s Find feature, with the following regular expression:
`(?<=<!\[CDATA\[).*?(?=\]\]>)`

See http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions for more details on how to use Regular Expressions in Notepad++.